# jQuery form plugin - iframe problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, forms

Here I am, with another problem. :) Maybe this time I'll get some responses. :P I'm using `jquery.form.js` plugin, to process forms with file fields.  It's simple implementation.

```
$this.ajaxSubmit({

  data: { 'ajax' : 'true' },
  dataType: 'html',
  success: parseRsp,
  error: parseErr

});
```

It works on Chrome, Opera and new Firefoxes. It doesnt on Firefox 3.x and all versions of IE. Plugin throws some `Server abort` problem, but after some changes in code to debug it, I get it. `Function getDoc(iframe)` throws `Permission denied` in IE. But why? It's not cross-domain or something? I even add `<script>document.domain = 'mydomain.com';</script>` but that doesn't work either. Any ideas?

BTW. we are using APE Project. It probably makes some document.domain modifications, but on Chrome console, on page where is form, when I type document.domain i'm still getting `mydomain.com`, so...

Comment: Please let me know how you specify file fields in AJAX. They require special multi-part prototol.

Comment: I don't understand? It's iframe implementation from jquery.form.js plugin. I don't specify fields in AJAX.

Comment: Explanation: as you say in AJAX you don't specify the fields. However you still must specify multi-part for file upload fields.

Comment: anyone figured out how to fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue just now.

The problem was that I was setting the `document.domain` property in the parent document. The api document that is inside the iframe is vanilla json, and, as such, has no opportunity of setting a `document.domain`. Hence the permission issue.

So I had to remove the `document.domain` assignment from the parent.